# Input text has too few parameters - C# Discord bot

Tags: c#, discord

I'm pretty new to all of this, so excuse the fact that this is probably a massive facepalm moment to most people here. I'm trying to get my Discord bot to play audio. It'll join the channel but whenever I use the play command it says "the input text has too few parameters" in the discord chat. As I said I'm new to this so don't know where to start. Here's what I have for the play command;

```
[Command("play", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
public async Task PlayCmd([Remainder] string song)
{

    await _service.SendAudioAsync(Context.Guild, Context.Channel, song);
}
}
```

That's just the basic play command I have with nothing extra added just yet. Also, how would I get it to play a specific file? I'm unsure of where or how to add the file path to the command.

Comment: What are you passing to `PlayCmd`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Joe4evr/773d3ce6cc10dbea6924d59bbfa3c62a/308f8fd92e03febcb699023d95a4f0a8813aa46f https://github.com/moiph/ub3r-b0t/blob/master/src/Utilities/AudioManager.cs you might want to check out these

Comment: I used those links you provided already, but cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided I assume that you need to give the song-name as the parameter in your command. The function `PlayCmd` does take a `string` as a parameter.
Try to use your commad in discord like this syntax:

> `command` `parameter`

. For example: `play Tetris`

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot... Now I have a new problem. When I add a parameter, nothing happens. I get no error and no sound is played. Would this be because I don't have an instance of AudioService added to IServiceProvider? Whenever I try to add it using `_services = new ServiceCollection().AddSingleton(new AudioService());` I get an error "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to 'System.IServiceProvider'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @ConnorPrice Im sorry i cant help you any further. I dont have the source code and I havent worked with the discord bot.